# Oracle SQL efficiency

Tags: sql

I have this query that gets almost a thousand records. The problem is the return of data is so slow about a minute or two.

Here is my query

```
SELECT POLNO, COLID, FORCEWRITE, INSURETAG, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(STARTDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS STARTDT, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EXPIRYDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EXPIRYDT, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DUEDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DUEDT, CANTAG, PREMAMT, NETPREM FROM LPCINS WHERE CANTAG IS NULL AND COLID IN (SELECT COLID FROM LCCOLASS WHERE LOANNO IN (SELECT LOANNO FROM TMPPORT3)) ORDER BY EXPIRYDT DESC
```

Is there a way to improve this? I also have an index placed but it is still slow. I am using oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this using `exists`:

```
SELECT POLNO, COLID, FORCEWRITE, INSURETAG, 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(STARTDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS 
STARTDT,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EXPIRYDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EXPIRYDT, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DUEDT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DUEDT,
       CANTAG, PREMAMT, NETPREM
FROM LPCINS L
WHERE CANTAG IS NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM LCCOLASS LC JOIN
                   TMPPORT3 T
                   ON LC.LOANNO = T.LOANNO
              WHERE L.COLID = LC.COLID
             )
ORDER BY EXPIRYDT DESC
```

Then try an index on `LPCINS(CANAG, COLID)` and `LCCOLASS(COLID, LOANNO)` and `TMMPORT3(LOANNO)`.

Comment: It still a bit slow but it was cutdown to 45 seconds